# How to find the last column using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

I want to copy the data from `G11:G22` to the last column of the sheet starting from row 11 by using `onEdit` function. So, the script will be triggered once I select `Transfer` in cell `F7`. After running the script, the data should appear in range `H11:H22` since column H is the last column in the sheet. How should I achieved that? This is what I have tried:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastrow = ss.getLastRow()

  for( var k = 2; k <= lastrow ; k++) {
    var m = 1; 
      while( sheet.getRange(k,m).isBlank() == false) {
        m = m +1;
      }
      var lastcolumn = m
  }
  var destRange = ss.getRange(11,lastcolumn+1)
  
  if (e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart == 7){
    if (e.value == 'Transfer'){
      var source = ss.getRange("G11:G22")
      source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true})
      e.range.clearContent()
   }
  }
}
```

I think the problem comes from the `For loop` but I have no idea what is wrong. Hope to get some helps on this, thank you.

Comment: Based on your screenshot: why can't you just use `ss.getLastColumn()` method? It should give you number 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshot I suppose you can use `getLastColumn()`

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var destRange = ss.getRange(11, ss.getLastColumn() + 1)

  if (e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart == 7) {
    if (e.value == 'Transfer') {
      var source = ss.getRange("G11:G22")
      source.copyTo(destRange, { contentsOnly: true })
      e.range.clearContent()
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

No need `for` loop to get the last column if there is no more filled cels on the right side of the sheet.